# ConfigurationBuilder Twitter4j class not found

Tags: configuration, builder, twitter4j

Sorry, but it seems i cannot find any ConfigurationBuilder class in Twitter4j.

I'm using twitter4j version 3.0.3. I have already tried 3.0.2 android version too.

I have added the jar to build path like core, async, media, and stream.

I tried to :

```
- import twitter4j.*;
- import twitter4j.conf.*;
- import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;
```

But Eclipse says that :

```
Multiple markers at this line
- ConfigurationBuilder cannot be resolved to a 
 type
- ConfigurationBuilder cannot be resolved to a 
 type
```

What do i need?

I have already checked the source folders and there is a class named ConfigurationBuilder.java.

Thank you!

Comment: the twitter4j jar file you are adding should be from the `core` folder of the zip file you downloaded from the website

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure that Android Dependencies folder.  To do that, you copy the twitter4j jar file to the libs folder and then right click to Configure Path and add the library.

After that's done, you will see that the library is also copied to the dependencies folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Right click on the project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries
2. Make sure that twitter4j-core-x.y.z.jar is really there
3. Go also to Order and Export tab in the same dialog
4. Make sure that the twitter4j-core-x.y.z.jar is selected (to get the jar distributed with the *.apk or else you will get something similar to the following at runtime: could not find class ConfigurationBuilder)
5. Project > Clean
6. Project > Build All